Remove special word using gsub
I try to clean some text and I would like to remove the following text from a string

googletag.cmd.push(function() {
googletag.display('div-gpt-ad-1513202928332-3'); });

For example, if
x="123 googletag.cmd.push(function() { googletag.display('div-gpt-ad-1513202928332-3'); }); 456"

then
gsub("googletag.cmd.push(function() { googletag.display('div-gpt-ad-1513202928332-3'); });, ", x)

The desired output is [1] 123456
Thank you

Regex approach
You can use the following pattern.
x <- "123 googletag.cmd.push(function() { googletag.display('div-gpt-ad-1513202928332-3'); }); 456"

gsub("^(\\d+).*?(\\d+)$", "\\1\\2", x)
# [1] "123456"

Explanation:

We keep the groups of digits at the start and end (groups 1 and 2) and discard everything in between. We use a non-greedy regex in between to ensure we capture all digits in both groups.
Non-regex approach
It's a little difficult to tell with one example, but if it's always the number at the beginning and the end of the string, you don't need regex. You can just split on spaces and take the first and last element:
strsplit(x, " ", fixed = TRUE) |>
    sapply(\(m) paste0(head(m, 1), tail(m, 1)))
# [1] "123456"


You can simply run
> sub("\\s.*\\s", "", x)
[1] "123456"


This removes literally +1!

We could paste the regmatches derived from gregexpr.
> do.call('paste', c(regmatches(x, gregexpr(r'{^\d+|\d+$}', x)), list(collapse='')))
[1] "123456"

To address your comment and also capture some letters, try:
> x2 <- "123 ABC googletag.cmd.push(function() { googletag.display('div-gpt-ad-1513202928332-3'); }); 456"
> do.call('paste', c(regmatches(x, gregexpr(r'{^\d+\s\w+|\s\d+$}', x2)), list(collapse='')))
[1] "123 ABC 456"


Thank you all. What if I have some characters after 123 (i.e ABC) that should be displayed after gsub (i.e 123 ABC 456)
